# org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject at com.tpg.json.JsonParsing.main(JsonParsing.java:24)

Tags: java, json, http

I'm trying to read user id and user role from the following JSON file :

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X6t2kKaYArwM-mLc4EQhPAfUWF95RYTW/view?usp=sharing][1]

I have added both erp.json and class file in the same package : com.tpg.json

I'm using json simple jar file.

And facing the error : org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject

Could you suggest me the edits and re-post the code?

You can post your code or another code as well,which will give me the required output.

```
 package com.tpg.json;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

//com.googlecode.json-simple
public class JsonParsing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassLoader classLoader = new JsonParsing().getClass().getClassLoader();
        String fileName = "com/tpg/json/erp.json";
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath());
            Object obj = parser.parse(reader);
            JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;

            JSONObject res = (JSONObject) jsonObj.get("Resources");
            System.out.println("studentDetails :" + res.toJSONString());

            JSONArray ID = (JSONArray) res.get("id");
            System.out.println("Id" + ID);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please do not post external links to data. You should post minimal json, that we will be able to use to reproduce the error, in your question.

Comment: @michalk,JSON output is so big that I have to add it for the understanding and to know the complexity. So that other people can answer or edit the code accordingly.